# error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1 in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to develop app with Xamarin.Android but I am getting error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1 when I try to build my app.

I have been searching solutions about this topic but I couldnt fix it.

This is full error:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.D8.targets(51,5): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.

This is the page where I double clicked:

```
 <R8
        Condition=" '$(_UseR8)' == 'True' "
        ToolPath="$(JavaToolPath)"
        JavaMaximumHeapSize="$(JavaMaximumHeapSize)"
        JavaOptions="$(JavaOptions)"
        JarPath="$(AndroidR8JarPath)"
        AndroidManifestFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml"
        OutputDirectory="$(_AndroidIntermediateDexOutputDirectory)"
        Debug="$(AndroidIncludeDebugSymbols)"
        JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)"
        ClassesZip="$(_AndroidIntermediateClassesZip)"
        JavaLibrariesToEmbed="@(_JavaLibrariesToCompileForApp);@(_InstantRunJavaReference)"
        JavaLibrariesToReference="@(AndroidExternalJavaLibrary)"
        EnableDesugar="$(AndroidEnableDesugar)"
        AndroidSdkBuildToolsPath="$(AndroidSdkBuildToolsPath)"
        AcwMapFile="$(_AcwMapFile)"
        ProguardCommonXamarinConfiguration="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg"
        ProguardGeneratedReferenceConfiguration="$(_ProguardProjectConfiguration)"
        ProguardGeneratedApplicationConfiguration="$(IntermediateOutputPath)proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg"
        ProguardMappingFileOutput="$(AndroidProguardMappingFile)"
        ProguardConfigurationFiles="@(_ProguardConfiguration)"
        EnableShrinking="$(_R8EnableShrinking)"
        EnableMultiDex="$(AndroidEnableMultiDex)"
        MultiDexMainDexListFile="$(_AndroidMainDexListFile)"
        CustomMainDexListFiles="@(MultiDexMainDexList)"
        IgnoreWarnings="$(AndroidR8IgnoreWarnings)"
        ExtraArguments="$(AndroidR8ExtraArguments)"
    />
```

Comment: Are you meeting this issue after updating to the latest version of VS2019 ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT No but I am using the latest version of VS2019. I mean I was using the latest version when I try to develop app.

Comment: Try enable Multi-Dex in android project settings

Comment: @NickKovalsky I did but it did not work

Comment: disable code shrinker?

Comment: @NickKovalsky it is not selected, should I select r8?

Comment: Nope its ok. Another cause i can think of is conflicting versions of android libs in used nugets..

Comment: @NickKovalsky yes it was the problem and I fix it with creating a new project and loaded it paying attention to the versions of the packets.Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: Please go to your project properties and change Linking to SDK and UserAssemblies